# Can I use a Disney character name as a nickname for one of my staff members in an interview video?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, fair-use, name

I am working as a graphic designer for a small team of researchers in a national research organization. One of our team members is affectionately called "Baymax" from the film "Big Hero Six".

I am currently creating a promo video that demonstrates the technology we are working on. This video is interview style and I would like to have a title card that displays the researcher's name and then underneath that his internal nickname "Baymax". I am wondering though if this falls under fair use or if it is a bad idea.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names are not subject to copyright so "fair use" is not applicable.

Names can be (and in this case are) trade marks. Trade marks do not have a fair use exemption. You are allowed to use a trade mark to refer to the trade marked product (that's what they are for). You can also use a trade mark generally provided that it is clear (implicitly or explicitly) that there is no relationship between you and the trade mark and it does not compete with the trade mark's business interests.

Comment: Thank you! So by this, "You can also use a trade mark generally provided that it is clear (implicitly or explicitly) that there is no relationship between you and the trade mark and it does not compete with the trade mark's business interests." do you mean it would be okay to use said trade mark as a nickname for my co-worker? Or is that a violation?